# Wi-Fi adaptor is not found after Ubuntu 18.04 is installed

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04. But the Wi-Fi adaptor is missing.

```
$lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2123]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I also tried to use my cellphone to do the USB tethering and run

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

but I got

```
Need to get 0 B/28.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 125 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
```

I was using a USB drive to boot and installed the Ubuntu not sure why the system is not able to found the file.

The last thing I tried is: to go to the 'Software & updates' -> 'additional Drivers' -> 'Broadcom Limited: BCM4352 802.11ac wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source'.

I selected that option and applied the change. But after that, the progress bar for 'Applying changes...' is frozen, the operation can not be done.

Any suggestion about how to enable my Wi-Fi adaptor?